# How can I write a purescript effect handler that subracts an effect from the set

Tags: purescript

PureScript by Example, in the section [The Eff Monad -> Handlers and Actions](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-handlers-and-actions) states that "[an effect] handler usually subtracts effects from the set". However, the examples are rather opaque and I can't work out how to write my own handler to achieve this.

Specifically, I'm working with purescript-aff and [purescript-affjax](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-affjax). I'd like to use runAff (from purescript-aff) in combination with get (from purescript-affjax).

The problem is that `get` uses the Affjax monad, whereas `runAff` expects something using the Aff monad.

Affjax is defined as:

```
type Affjax e a = Aff (ajax :: AJAX | e) (AffjaxResponse a)
```

Aff is defined as:

```
foreign import data Aff :: # ! -> * -> *
```

I, therefore, want to write a function that has the following type:

```
Affjax e a -> Aff e a
```

This seems to me to require a handler that subtracts the `ajax` part of the effect set. How would one code such a handler?

Attempting to pattern-match, as below, of course results in the error `unexpected |`.

```
handleAffjax :: Affjax e a -> Aff e a
handleAffjax (Aff ( | eff1 ) resp1) = Aff eff1 resp1
```

Thanks all.

### Update

Inspired by [@christoph-hegemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697564/4445916%20@christoph-hegemann's%20answer%20below)'s answer below, I was able to track down most of the issues with my code.

I think the answer to the question in the title is that one does not subtract an effect from the set, and that description is a little confusing. The effect remains after you've handled it.

The intuition I was missing is that I have to add the expected effects to the calling function type. The lack of a type declaration on `main` hid that to some extent. I worked it out when I turned Christoph's example into the following compiling example:

```
module Main where

import Debug.Trace
import Network.HTTP.Affjax
import Control.Monad.Aff
import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception

initialUrl :: URL
initialUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/navitem/2/"

runGet :: forall e. Eff (ajax :: AJAX, trace :: Trace | e) Unit
runGet = runAff errorHandler successHandler (get initialUrl)

errorHandler :: forall e. Error -> Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Unit
errorHandler err = print err

successHandler :: forall e. AffjaxResponse String -> Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Unit
successHandler res = print res.response

main = runGet
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take it step by step ^^

> The problem is that get uses the Affjax monad, whereas runAff expects something using the Aff monad.
>
> Affjax is defined as:
>
> `type Affjax e a = Aff (ajax :: AJAX | e) (AffjaxResponse a)`

Affjax is a **type synonym**. This means that Affjax is not it's own Monad but instead a special case of the Aff Monad. Let's take a look at that next:

> Aff is defined as:
>
> `foreign import data Aff :: # ! -> * -> *`

So Aff is a type constructor that takes *2 Types as Arguments* to produce a new type. The *kind* of the first argument is # ! which tells us that:

- # -> It's a row ...
- ! -> ... made up out of effects

So when you look at the definition of the Affjax type synonym you can see that the first argument to the Aff type constructor is a row of effects which contains the `ajax :: Ajax` effect but is open for extension `| e`.

The second argument to Aff is just a type which in the case of Affjax an AffjaxResponse parameterised by the type variable a.

Looking at [Pursuit](http://pursuit.purescript.org/?q=AffjaxResponse) reveals that AffjaxResponse is merely a type synonym for a record so you can access it's members by using the dot operator.

I've put together a minimal compiling example which should get you started:

```
module Main where

import Debug.Trace
import Network.HTTP.Affjax
import Control.Monad.Aff
import Control.Monad.Eff
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception

errorHandler :: forall e. Error -> Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Unit
errorHandler err = print err

successHandler :: forall e. AffjaxResponse String -> Eff (trace :: Trace | e) Unit
successHandler res = print res.response

main = runAff errorHandler successHandler (get "http://www.myApi.com/api" )
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking things down @christoph-hegemann. I'd obviously stacked up a few confusions. I'm not sure you answered the question in the title, but I've marked your answer as accepted because you did help me fix my specific problem.

Comment: @mjkaye glad I could help! I think your updated question answers it better than mine ;)